# Call default implementation of protocol method from NSNotification event

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a protocol intended to be used by `UIViewController`s that has two default implementations of methods

```
protocol RotationMonitor {

    func registerForRotationNotifications()

    func viewDidRotate()
}

extension RotationMonitor where Self: UIViewController {
    func registerForRotationNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "viewDidRotate", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func viewDidRotate() {
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
        case .LandscapeLeft, .LandscapeRight:
            print("Device is landscape")
        case .Portrait:
            print("Device is portrait")
        case .PortraitUpsideDown:
            print("Device is portrait, upside down.")
        default:
            // ignore
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling these methods directly in a view controller's code works fine for both methods; calling `registerForRotationNotifications()` registers the view controller for device rotation notifications, and calling `viewDidRotate()` performs the switch statement properly. However, after calling `registerForRotationNotifications()` and receiving an actual notification, I get a crash with the message

```
2015-11-03 10:46:53.111 APP_NAME[57415:2484548] -[APP_NAME.ViewController viewDidRotate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8afb019a00
```

I thought that this was maybe because the view controller wasn't offering public access to the `viewDidRotate()` method, but I'm unable to use the `public` keyword on any of the protocol method definitions or default implementations.

Is there any way to get the notification center to properly call the default implementation in the protocol extension? I don't want to have to use a workaround like calling the `viewDidRotate()` method from the view controller itself, I'd like to be able to have the view controller simply register for notifications and have the work offloaded onto the protocol extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this the way you're trying to do it. Remember, Objective-C knows only Objective-C language features. It knows nothing of Swift enums, structs, generics, tuples, etc.; such Swift features are completely invisible to Objective-C. In the same way, Objective-C knows nothing of Swift protocols, and especially nothing of Swift protocol extensions. As far as Objective-C is concerned, the `viewDidRotate` method is not present in the view controller class. Hence the crash.

Comment: Okay, so since `NSNotificationCenter` is written in Obj-C, this is just never going to work (short of UIKit getting rewritten in Swift)? That's a bummer, but it makes sense.

Comment: _All_ of Cocoa is written in Objective-C. Programming iOS means you are talking to Objective-C _constantly_, except when you are just talking to yourself. My book gives you a good summary of the limited view Objective-C has of your Swift code: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects